# Display Emoji in UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield, emoji

I am trying to add emoji in `UITextField` with existing text.But I get only unicode in the textfield in place of emoji like `\ue415`. I have try the below code to set emoji in the textfield.

I have a view in which there are buttons with images of emojis. on the click of that emoji i am appending the respective unicode of that emoji to the text. but in that unicode is appended in string format and not the actual symbol.

If I try to set direct unicode in the textfield then it show the emoji but if i try to get the value from array then it is not showing the emoji.

```
NSString *strCode = [[arrPlist objectAtIndex:[sender tag]]objectForKey:@"UTFCode"];
strCode = [strCode stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

NSString *mycode = @"\ue415";
if ([mycode isEqualToString:strCode]) 
 {
     NSLog(@"both are same");
 }
NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"strCode:%@ and mycode:%@",strCode,mycode]);
messageField.text = [messageField.text stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@ %@",strCode,mycode];
```

And the output is like :

**strCode:\ue415 and mycode:**

Can anyone help me with how can i get the strCode same as myCode ?

Comment: i think the emoji icon will not show in the console window.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365450/nsstring-with-unicode-issue-from-web-service?rq=1
 go this link,that is your answer..!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
Use like below it will work  

 NSString *myString = @"I am sad of him";
 myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"sad" withString:@"\ue415"];
 txtField.text = myString;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
But actually I have a view in which there are buttons with images of emojis.
 on the click of that emoji i am appending the respective unicode of that emoji to the text. but in that unicode is appended in string format and not the actual symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.

you can not put \ character as a string. in your code 'mycode' takes the @"\ue415" in one character not as string. you can see it with

```
NSlog(@"%d",[mycode length]);
```

... it will show you 1 instead of 6.

if you can set -

```
NSString *mycode = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\\"]stringByAppendingFormat:@"ue415"]);
```

any how in your code....this will give you the string what you want.

Thank You!!

Comment: Thanks For The Reply.Actually I was getting the length 6 only.but now i got the solution.

I was getting the array from the plist file and so that i was not getting the string instead of unicode.
So I made an array of unicodes and got it like this :



`arrEmojis = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"\ue415",@"\ue056",@"\ue057",@"\ue414",@"\ue405",@"\ue106",@"\ue418",@"\ue417",@"\ue40d",@"\ue40a",@"\ue404",@"\ue105", nil];


NSString *strCode = [arrEmojis objectAtIndex:[sender tag]];


messageField.text = [messageField.text stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@",strCode];`