# NSString with Unicode issue from Web Service

Tags: iphone, xcode, unicode, nsstring

I have tried to search in Stackoverflow. But I could not get the correct solution. Can someone please help me?

I have this data from a web service.

```
KEY: 1036   TYPE: string    VALUE = French (fran\u00E7aise)
KEY: 1032   TYPE: string    VALUE = Greek  (\u03B5\u03BB\u03BB\u03B7\u03BD\u03B9\u03BA\u03AC)
```

Does anyone know how to print this Unicode string correctly? I have tried to encode and decode it back (as shown below). But it is not working. :(

```
NSString *value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", t.dataValue]; 
NSData *bytes = [message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString* messageDecoded = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:bytes encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"decoded: %@", messageDecoded);
```

Thanks in advance guys!

### ANSWER:

I got an answer from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099349/using-objective-c-cocoa-to-unescape-unicode-characters-ie-u1234):

```
NSString* input = @"ab\"cA\"BC\\u2345\\u0123";
// will cause trouble if you have "abc\\\\uvw"
NSString* esc1 = [input stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\u" withString:@"\\U"];
NSString* esc2 = [esc1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""];
NSString* quoted = [[@"\"" stringByAppendingString:esc2] stringByAppendingString:@"\""];
NSData* data = [quoted dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString* unesc = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:data
  mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:NULL
  errorDescription:NULL];
assert([unesc isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]);
NSLog(@"Output = %@", unesc);
```

Comment: It's because that's not UTF-8. It's ASCII or ISO-Latin-1 or some such with escaped unicode characters. If you can get your web service to actuallly send you a UTF-8 encoded string, that'd be ideal. If not, you'll have to iterate over the returned string and unescape the characters.

Comment: Hey Jason, what do you mean by unescape the characters? What I am confused is that if I do "NSLog(@"fran\u00E7aise")", it prints the correct string ! :(

Comment: It prints that because the compiler unescaped the characters for you and converted the string to UTF-8 before writing it to your apps static data section.

Comment: Thanks.. It is starting to get clear now !